# IIB SOAPRequest node authentication

Tags: authentication, soap-client, ibm-integration-bus

I use IIB Web User Interface to set SecurityProfile but I am not sure the command is right or not:

> mqsicreateconfigurableservice DEVTEST -c SecurityProfiles -o TEST_SECPROF -n propagation,passwordValue,idToPropagateToTransport,transportPropagationConfig -v "TRUE","PLAIN","STATIC ID","TEST_USER"

How can I add the created security profile to a SOAPRequest node, please?

I also tried to set these parameters but in vain:

```
SET OutputRoot.Properties.IdentitySourceType='usernameAndPassword';
SET OutputRoot.Properties.IdentitySourceToken = 'username';
SET OutputRoot.Properties.IdentitySourcePassword = 'password';
```

I have read about this command but I want to apply authentication already in the debug, too:

```
mqsiapplybaroverride -b barFileName -k applicationName -m 
   flowName#nodeName.securityProfileName=securityProfileName
```

Comment: Setting the security profile with the mqsiapplybaroverride command should work, you need to deploy the BAR first before debugging.

Comment: Hello Attila! Just you are as always. Thank you!
I tried it and I tried to set it in toolkit but it was interesting because I could set the policy and binding but not the security profile. My custom sec. polyce is nowhere. I have read somewhere there is no need to create a custom sec. pol., it is enough to use the default but it is not working for me. (AuthenticationNotFound) Authentication not found.

Comment: It depends on what security you want in your flow, if propagating the incoming identity is enough, then the default security profile is what you need. The security profile defines what security operations you want (e.g. authentication, authorization, identity mapping), the security policies and bindings configure input nodes to handle WS-Security elements in the messages (e.g. how to extract or export the security identity from or to the messages).

Comment: Maybe these help: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ap04170_.htm https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ap04090_.htm